# How to use Facebook for Developers share button using localhost

Tags: facebook, xampp, localhost, facebook-share

I'm trying to have a Facebook share button which shares the link of the current page. I am using localhost and Facebook is unable to reach my website since I'm using localhost (xampp). Is there any way to get around this? I have seen people mention about using tunnelme, but I don't see a tutorial on how to do it. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My technique to deal with this kind of issue is define some fake domain in /etc/hosts (Linux o MacOS) or C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts in Windows.

something like:

```
127.0.0.1    customdomain.liquidtabs
```

(Do not use .devel because now is a valid TLD and cause some collisions).

In the last time, I'm using a local DNS server (like dnsmasq) to define multiple custom local fake domains.

Finally, in your Facebook app configuration, you must add your fake domain as an allowed domain to access the API.

In the last time, Google Developers Console requires a valid domain (for example, finished in .com, like mycustomfakedomain.com). I do not remember if Facebook too.

In this case, you must define a "valid" domain and override it in the **hosts** file. Like:

```
127.0.0.1    customdomain.local.liquidtabs.com
```

Now, run your website using your fake domain. You should now be able to access Facebook from the library (or Google or any other domain-restricted library) from "localhost".

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking me to do.

Comment: That is fine for testing stuff that happens in the user's browser (like the login flow redirects) - but it won't work for sharing. Facebook needs to be able to read the Open Graph meta data from the URL, and that is something a locally set up domain can not help with.

Comment: CBroe do you know of a way to do it? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. @CBroe is right, Facebook Crawler must access to read the shared URL. The only way I know to test the shared content is publishing your website.